# Why can't we use single object for both dependent and independent matrices in Feature Scaling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, data-science, non-linear-regression

```
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
Y = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)
```

Why can't we use a single `StandardScaler()` object to fit both X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending both values to `X`. [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) as `Y` with default value `None`. You need to send the together

```
sc = StandardScaler()
sc_transform(X=X, y=Y)
```

Comment: Can we use a single object?

Answer (score 0):

`StandardScaler` is transforming your data such that its distribution will have a mean value 0 and standard deviation of 1.
So i doesn't make sense to fit different 2 data in the same method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the mean and standard deviation functions in feature scaling?